# How to handle the token before the page load?

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt

I use JWT for authenticated (Without login page).
I have some problem that when the site load the first thing that start is the get methods for load the content and after the authentication methods and save the token in local storage.

The problem is i get error that i not authenticated and after i refresh the page its work. 
I need to make him first make the authentication methods and save him to local storage and after that he load the pages.

Auth.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../http/http.service';
import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  public isDialogOpen = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpService) { }

  authUser(userID) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token') === null) {
      this.http.authUser(userID).subscribe((data) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }

  removeToken() {
    localStorage.clear();
  }

  getCurrentUser() {
    try {
      const jwt = localStorage.getItem('token');
      return jwt_decode(jwt);
    } catch (error) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

header.interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class HeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const token = localStorage.token;
        if (!token) {
          return next.handle(request);
        }

        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'x-auth-token': token
            }
        });
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Error.interceptor.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`Server Error`);
                }
                if (err.status === 401) {
                    this.authService.authUser('1');
                }
                const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
                return throwError(error);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using a Route Guard with your auth service?

Comment: i implement now Route Guard but the problem is i get the token after the page load

Answer (score 1):

You should keep your code separated. Your requests handling should not wait explicitly on the authentication to succeed: instead, use observables all around.

A very good example of how to go with that is the [Auth0 help page](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login). Even if you don't use Auth0 backend, the architecture is the one to go for: your auth service returns the token as an observable and other places where you need it subscribe to the observable.

Also, [you should not use localStorage to store your tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens) or Cookies for that matter. Instead, retrieve it with standard OAuth protocol (dedicated services such as Okta, Auth0 or open source alternatives provide  SDKs that take care of that).

For example with [Auth0 SDK](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/02-calling-an-api):

> Why isn't the token stored in browser storage? Historically, it was
>   common to store tokens in local or session storage. However, browser
>   storage is not a secure place to store sensitive data. The
>   auth0-spa-js SDK manages session retrieval for you so that you no
>   longer need to store sensitive data in browser storage in order to
>   restore sessions after refreshing a Single Page Application.
>
> With auth0-spa-js, we can simply request the token from the SDK when
>   we need it (e.g., in an HTTP interceptor) rather than storing it
>   locally in the Angular app or browser. The SDK manages token freshness
>   as well, so we don't need to worry about renewing tokens when they
>   expire.

Note: I'm not affiliated with Auth0, just used the service on my latest project :)

Comment: There’s bad reasons to use cookies for auth tokens too.  You have to consider different security issues in either case but both can be mitigated.

Comment: Yes, and using a standard client-side library is a good guarantee to stay safe.

Comment: Right, I realize I misunderstood Auth0 SDK, they actually do not store the token at all. Edited in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

One way to wait is via Promises - have a promise that doesn’t resolve until your authentication returns, and then await that promise before accessing your token from localStorage.